# How to check password strength only after min characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm using the AjaxControlToolKit's PasswordStrength control. Once the user begins typing anything into the control, it starts displaying a message that the password is weak. I would like this message to appear only after the mininum number of characters have been typed in.  I don't see anything on the control that allows this functionality.  Any suggestions on how I should handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably going to need to roll your own solution for this which makes sense if you think about it.  By hiding the visual cue that a password of two characters is weak but displaying it for a password of three characters would seem to imply that the two character password is sufficient.

That being said what you *might* be able to do is write some sort of hack similar to this:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function onPasswordChange(textBox) {
      var passwordLabel = document.getElementById([labelID]);
      if(textBox.value.length < [constant]){
          passwordLabel.style.display = 'none';
      }
      else{
          passwordLabel.style.display = 'inline';            
      } 
  }
</script>
```

You could then attach this function the controls <strike>change</strike> onKeyUp or onKeyDown event so that if the length of the password field was less than what you want it to be it will hide the label that contains the message that the strength has not been met. This is untested an only a thought.  You may wind up with issue from the toolkit javascript colliding with this script but it is tough to say.

Additionally the labelID looks to be [controlIDName]_PasswordStrength.

Edit:

You would probably want to add the <strike>onchange</strike> onKeyUp or onKeyDown event to your control like so (code behind):

<strike>control.Attributes.Add("onchange", "onPasswordChange(this)");</strike>

```
 control.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", "onPasswordChange(this)");
```

Edit 2:
As far as hacks go this is pretty messy but it works. Clientside:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<div id="PasswordStrengthContainer"></div>
<asp:PasswordStrength ID="PS" runat="server"
TargetControlID="password"  
DisplayPosition="RightSide"  
StrengthIndicatorType="Text"  
PreferredPasswordLength="10"  
PrefixText="Strength:"  
TextCssClass="TextIndicator_TextBox1"  
MinimumNumericCharacters="0"  
MinimumSymbolCharacters="0"  
RequiresUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters="false"  
TextStrengthDescriptions="Very Poor;Weak;Average;Strong;Excellent"  
TextStrengthDescriptionStyles="cssClass1;cssClass2;cssClass3;cssClass4;cssClass5"  
CalculationWeightings="50;15;15;20"
/>

 <script language="javascript">


function onPasswordChange(textBox) {
    var passwordLabel = document.getElementById("MainContent_password_PasswordStrength");
    var container = document.getElementById("PasswordStrengthContainer");

    if (passwordLabel != null) {
        document.getElementById("PasswordStrengthContainer").appendChild(
            document.getElementById("MainContent_password_PasswordStrength"));
    }

    if (textBox.value.length < 4) {
        container.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        container.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
 </script>
```

Serverside:

```
 password.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", "onPasswordChange(this)");
 password.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "onPasswordChange(this)");
```

This code is not efficient and could be cleaned up but works for demonstrative purposes.  The javascript function is pretty basic however you will notice this line:

```
 if (passwordLabel != null) {
        document.getElementById("PasswordStrengthContainer").appendChild(
            document.getElementById("MainContent_password_PasswordStrength"));
    }
```

Unfortunately the toolkits javascript functions will fire AFTER your function so setting the display to 'none' is wiped out by the toolkit. what this code does is remove the label from the page and places it in the div then we merely set the display property of our div to whatever and that will effectively hide the label.  There is a singular bug though: when hitting backspace to delete characters the div doesn't disappear in certain instances.  I don't really have time to track down the issue but it should be trivial for you to clear it up.

Additionally I was having some problems with onChange in Chrome so opted for onKeyDown instead as @Adriano pointed out above.

Comment: *"would seem to imply that the two character password is sufficient"* A two char password is *illegal* in the system.  Since it can't be done at all, it doesn't matter if it's strong or weak.  It's also possible there is message indicating "you haven't met the min char limit" which goes away at the same time.

Comment: I understand that requirement but what I am saying is that if the control does not display a warning to the user until the third character is typed then it would give the impression to the user that a two character password is valid.  I would agree that a message that the minimum length has not been met would be an acceptable substitute to displaying nothing.

Comment: After typing less than the minimum requirement of characters, once the user tabs out and into the confirm password textbox, it will display an error message about the minimum.

Comment: Interesting.  Try attaching the javascript function to the onBlur event in the same manner you attached it to the onChange event. You might need the function attached to both events.

Comment: onChange and onBlur aren't hitting when I'm typing anything in.  Only when I click out does the JS trigger.

Comment: I've updated my post with sample code that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I got to the point where the toolkit was overriding my work just before you posted.  I'll look into your update.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to get around the fact that this will override anything my client script does.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand?  In my example above this code runs and then the javascript from the toolkit runs.  What is being overridden?

Answer (score 2):

Attach to the client-side <strike>`change`</strike> `keyup` event of the text input. There you can add/remove a special CSS class in the `TextCssClass` (if you're using text) with just one rule: `display: none` (using the text length as condition).

Comment: Can you give an example of how a conditional can be used?

Comment: @4thSpace code provided from abszero is good, the "change" event is pretty elusive. Attach your event handler to the "keyup" event (it's what PasswordStrength control does: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/2c482e5ad6c4#Client%2fMicrosoftAjax.Extended%2fPasswordStrength%2fPasswordStrengthExtenderBehavior.pre.js).

Comment: Note: I prefer the property TextCssClass over the direct access to the label with getElementById 'cause it won't be broken if something change in the control but it works anyway.

Comment: @Adriano - That is a good point about the change event.  In my updated code below I opted for onKeyDown but using onKeyUp would of worked just as well.